# JFreeChart ignoring lower values in Pie Chart

Tags: jfreechart

Method to create dataset:

```
private static DefaultPieDataset getPieDataset(List<ChartObject> list)
{
   DefaulPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
   for(ChartObject object : list)
       dataset.setValues(object.getKey(), object.getValueX());

   return dataset;
}
```

My list contains three object with following values:

Key: HIGH Value: 9

Key: MEDIUM Value: 30

Key: LOW Value: 46

But my pie chart show only two categories LOW & MEDIUM. HIGH is completely ignored.

[image: Pie Chart]

A quick Google Search showed me that we can set threshold aggregate the lower values so I gave it a shot and changed the return type of my function to PieDataSet and the return statement to:

```
return DatasetUtilities.createConsolidatedPieDataset(dataset, "Other", 0);
```

But still no luck.

How do I force JFreeChart to not to ignore the lower value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your `List<ChartObject>` is wrong somehow, and your `getPieDataset()` doesn't compile. Here's an example that uses a `Map<String, Integer>`.

[image]

```
private Map<String, Integer> getData() {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("High", 9);
    map.put("Medium", 30);
    map.put("Low", 46);
    return map;
}

private ChartPanel createPieChart() {
    DefaultPieDataset data = new DefaultPieDataset();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : getData().entrySet()) {
        data.setValue(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return new ChartPanel(ChartFactory.createPieChart(
        "PieTest", data, true, true, false));
}
```